# Warning: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected in XXXXXXXX on line 53

Tags: php

I have the following PHP code which re-directs based on the grade

```
if ($grade == 'Admin')
{
    header("location:Admin\FINAL_adminhome.html");
}
else if ($grade == 'Employee')
{
    header("location:Admin\FINAL_adminhome.html");
}
else if ($grade == 'Security Guard')
{
    header("location:Security guard\securityhome.html");
}
else if ($grade == 'Receptionist')
{
    header("location: Reception\recphome.html"); // Line 53
}
```

---

For "Admin", "Employee" and "Security Guard", it redirects correctly. However, I get the following error for "Receptionist":

> Warning: Header may not contain more than a single header

Comment: Which line is line 53? Or do we guess?

Comment: Sorry :( Line 53: header("location: Reception\recphome.html");

Comment: Can't say I've seen all that many URL's with backslashes in them

Comment: I surprise that you are using location with space `header("location:Security guard\securityhome.html");` . I never see a url with space.

Answer (score 2):

\r means carriage return (ASCII code 13). Try escaping the slash like this

```
header("location: Reception\\recphome.html");
```

Comment: Thanks That worked.. I was so careless  :)

Comment: Glad that it worked!